# Asp.Net, DataGrid with dynamic columns doesn't fire SortCommand event

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

i have a simple DataGrid with some columns defined in .aspx(A) and some columns added programmatically in code behind(B).

The problem is that click on the header of columns (B) doesn't fire the SortCommand event; columns (A) works fine.

I noticed that re-DataBind() datasource at Page_Load make the things works, but i would avoid to do that becouse datasource can be very large(no session so) and retrive it is expansive.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to re-create dynamic controls on every postback. I would suggest `Page_Init`. Where do you create them?

Comment: I create them in Page_Load, i try Page_Init and I give you a feedback, thanks.

Comment: you have to create them on every postback but databind it only `if(!isPostBack)`

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you.